# Uniqueness of element in infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is an infinite Hilbert space where $\{e_k:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a total orthonormal family. Let $H_1=\overline{span{(e_k: k=0, 1,2,\cdots})}$ and $H_2=\overline{span{(e_{-k}+ke_k: k=1,2,\cdots})}.$ Is it true that $H_1\cap H_2=\{0\}$?

(Here, the bar represents closure of the set).

I think this claim is true due to orthogonality. If we pick an element $x\in H_1\cap H_2$. Then we can represent it as the following infinite sum: $x=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}<x,e_k>e_k=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}<x,e_{-k}+ke_k>(e_{-k}+ke_{k})$. Then using linearity of inner product, I am trying to get a system of equations from where I can say that the coefficients has to be $0.$ However,  I have not been able to get any cancellations using this approach.

Comment: Wouldn't e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ke_k$ be in the intersection?

Comment: @Math1000 This series does not converge.